# Flex Component using global variable

Tags: flex4, global-variables, flash-builder, custom-component

I am using Flash Builder 4 Burrito Preview - builing a Mobile Application.  I have a custom component called footer.mxml.  That footer has 4 buttons, and one of them has a lable that is bound to cartValue.  I am trying to maintain a global variable called cartValue within all views and footer component.

**footer.mxml**

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
   width="100%" height="64" chromeColor="#000000" fontSize="10">
<fx:Declarations>
  <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
  <mx:CurrencyFormatter id="currencyFormatter"
     currencySymbol="$"
     useThousandsSeparator="true"
     precision="2" />
 </fx:Declarations>



<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   [Bindable]
   public var cartValue:int;

  ]]>
</fx:Script>

 <s:HGroup width="100%" contentBackgroundColor="#000000" paddingBottom="0" paddingLeft="0"
 paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0">
 <s:Button x="0" y="624.5" width="25%" height="64" label="Account" chromeColor="#2259AA"
 enabled="true" fontSize="10" fontWeight="bold" icon="@Embed('assets/user.png')"/>
 <s:Button x="121" y="624.5" width="25%" height="64" label="Orders" chromeColor="#2259AA"
 fontSize="10" icon="@Embed('assets/doc_lines_stright.png')"/>
 <s:Button x="241" y="624.5" width="25%" height="64" label="Help" chromeColor="#2259AA" 
 fontSize="10" icon="@Embed('assets/spechbubble.png')"/>
 <s:Button x="360" y="624.5" width="25%" height="64" label="{currencyFormatter.format(cartValue)}" chromeColor="#2259AA" 
 fontSize="10" icon="@Embed('assets/shop_cart.png')"/>

 </s:HGroup>
    </s:Group>
```

**RincoTest.mxml**

```
 <s:MobileApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
  backgroundColor="#000000" firstView="views.RincoTestHome"
  >
 <fx:Style source="RincoTest.css"/>
<fx:Declarations>
 <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
 </fx:Declarations>
 <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

   [Bindable] 
   public var cartValue:int;
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>


 <s:titleContent>
  <s:Image left="1" top="3" width="173" height="75" backgroundAlpha="1.0" smooth="true"
 source="assets/iphone_large.png"/>
 </s:titleContent>
 <s:navigationContent>
  <mx:Spacer width="10" height="82"/>
 </s:navigationContent>


    </s:MobileApplication>
```

**And this is how I am implementing it**

```
<components:footer x="1.65" y="614.95" width="100%" height="64" cartValue="{cartValue}"/>
```

I have tried to bind Application.application.cartValue and
MobileApplication.application.cartValue.  Neither of them work.

If there is a better way to maintain a cartValue across the entire application please let me know.  This is my first attempt with Flex.

Thanks,
Ernie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static variable in the component.

Reference it as `ComponentName.staticVar`. Usually, everything that needs to know about the global already knows about (e.g. imports) the component file.

Cheers

Comment: Suppose I wanted to store a global variable so all views could access it.  What would be the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using a singleton pattern: a single instance that everything references through a static accessor.

The effect is about the same. The only advantage to a static reference to an instance over static properties is that the instance can be part of an inheritance and can fulfill an interface.

I've also had some intermittent problems with binding to static values, but that might have been a previous version, PEBCAK, etc.

Cheers